# CLJS/Reagent: React does not recognize the prop on a DOM element

Tags: clojurescript, reagent

I see there are lots of similar question in Javascript/React but I'm having this issue with CLojureScript/Reagent and I'm at a loss about how to solve it without messing up all my app-state names.

So I'm getting these warnings in the browser console:

```
react_devtools_backend.js:2430 Warning: React does not recognize the `showWarning` prop on a DOM element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom attribute, spell it as lowercase `showwarning` instead. If you accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM element.
```

These appear to be coming from the name of an item in the app-state:

```
(defonce app-state (reagent/atom {:show-warning "none"}))
```

The only solution I've found is to rename the item from **:show-warning** to **:showwarning** but this leads to a bunch of hard to read items.

I don't have any real control about how Reagent renames keys like :show-warning to "showWarning" but it seems this, being basic to how React works, would have a cleaner way to handle this.

Thanks!

Comment: If React is even aware of your app-state's keys, something is amiss.  Can you show the part of your program that is exposing app-state to a React DOM element?

Comment: @BipedPhill I'm not clear about what you're asking.  I don't have any direct React code as this is CLJS with Reagent.  Reagent wraps all the React bits so it's somewhat invisible.  But I agree, something is amiss.  None of these attrs should be passed to the DOM like this but I'm not sure about how it does this.

Comment: @jwh20 I'd wager somewhere in your code you have your state in the props position. Something like `[div @app-state]`. Possibly you were trying to render it and should've done `[div {} @app-state]`. This is a bit of a gotcha, since if you had something that evaluated to a string there it'd be fine, but a map reagent is going to try to treat like props.

Comment: @WaltonHoops I'll look through the code for a construct like that.  Thanks!

Comment: @WaltonHoops  Please post that as an answer!  I found a innocent looking call to a function that was doing a (swap!) on a key in the app-state atom but, of course, that returns the new app-state which was then placed inside a [:div] element.  Problem solved!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

React really shouldn't be able to see your state or care what's in it. My guess would be that you are rendering your state somewhere in the props positions. Most likely somewhere in your code you have `[:div @app-state]`. Possibly you were trying to render the state and should've done `[:div {} @app-state]`.

This is perhaps a bit of a gotcha with Reagent, since `[:p @im-a-string]` would render the string but `[:p @im-a-map]` will treat the map as props.